# How to copy the files from SFTP to target folder created dynamically based on source filename (Blob storage)?

Tags: copy, sftp, azure-data-factory

I am new to ADF, need help for 2 scenarios

```
1.I have to copy files from SFTP to blob storage(Azure Gnen2) using ADF. In the source SFTP folder, there are 3- 5 different the files. For example

S09353.DB2K.AFC00R46.F201130.txt
S09353.DB2K.XYZ00R46.F201130.txt
S09353.DB2K.GLY00R46.F201130.txt

On copying, this files are copied and placed under corresponding folders which are created dynamically based on file types.

For example: S09353.DB2K.AFC00R46.F201130.txt copy to  AFC00R46 folder
             S09353.DB2K.XYZ00R46.F201130.txt copy to XYZ00R46 folder.

2.Another requirement is need to copy csv files from blob storage to SFTP. On coping, the files need to copy to target folder created dynamically based on file name:

for example:  cust-fin.csv----->copy to--------->Finance folder
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution to your problem is to use Parameters in DataSets. This example is for a Blob Storage connection, but the approach is the same for SFTP as well. Another hint: if you are just moving files, use Binary DataSets.

**Create Parameter(s) in DataSet**
[image]

**Reference Parameter(s) in DataSet**
[image]

**Supply Parameter(s) in the Pipeline**
[image]

In this example, I am passing Pipeline parameters to a GetMetadata Activity, but the principles are the same for all DataSet types. The values could also be hard coded, expressions, or variables.

**Your Process**

If you need this to be dynamic for each file name, then you'll probably want to break this into parts:

1. Use a GetMetadata Activity to list the files from SFTP.
2. Foreach over the return list and process each file individually.
3. Inside the Foreach -> Parse each file name individually to extract the Folder name to a variable.
4. Inside the Foreach -> Use the Variable in a Copy Activity to populate the Folder name in the DataSet.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful. Considering that, please accept it as the answer, and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi,  I am implement this. But I am facing the issue on copying the files.As i said, need to copy the files into target folder which are picked by file type what we are passing as a pipleine parameter.           For example:

Comment: On doing, Facing the issue on copying the files.I need to copy the files into target folder which are picked by file type what we are passing as a pipleine parameter Example am passing type of the file to be copied with wildcard character i.e  Passing *XYZ00R46* as a parameter to copy XYZ00R46 files into XYZ00R46(extracted dynamically using substring from *XYZ00R46*) folder under target directory. But it is not copied as expected. Copying the files to folder XYZ00R46 and 'AFC00R46' and also create a folder on Fie name ic ADGV.DB2X.XYZ00R46.txt.I need to copy the file only to XYZ00R46 FOLDER.